# Micro sd locked internal storage

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, adoptable-storage

I configured my micro sd as internal storage in my moto g3 and I foolishly reseted the phone. So, now I can't access to all my photos because android tells me that I have to format the sd. The problem is that I really need to recover all my information. Is there any way in which I could unlocked the sd?
I'll apreciate your help since I am really desperate and nobody can give me any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Bad luck, I'm afraid. There are ways to decrypt the card, but they require the encryption key – which is gone with a factory-reset as well.